# Is .9999... in base 10 = .JJJ... in base 20 = 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ok, so I'm not a mathematician and I was arguing with a friend about .999... = 1. He made the argument that it's not because .95 was not the same as .90. In base 10, .9 is well, .9. However, in base 20, .J would be .95 in decimal. He then said that because .999... = 1 then .JJJ... also = 1. However, this leads us to the silly conclusion that .90 = .95. Because we can subtract .999... in decimal from .JJJ... and get something like .111... in base 20.

Is .JJJ... closer to 1 than .999...? Or do they both equal 1 and so .90 = .95? Or is there some mathematical trick that he's doing?

Comment: Yes. .9999999999... = 1

Comment: In base 20, 19 is represented by alphabet $J$

Comment: by .191919... I think he meant $.JJJJJJJJJJ...$

Comment: @Rustyn that makes a lot difference.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 19 \frac{1}{20^n} = 1$ and also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 9 \frac{1}{10^n}=1$.  But of course $\frac{9}{10} \neq \frac{19}{20}$.

Comment: maybe the convergence to 1 is faster, but they both still converge to 1...

Comment: You claim that the answers don't answer the "core" of your question. Can you be specific about what the core of your question is?

Comment: The core of the question is the relationship between .999... and .JJJ... and how even though they are different numbers, they both equal one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment that $0.J_{20}=0.95_{10}$ is correct and irrelevant to the discussion.  We are not talking about finite decimals, we are talking about infinite repeating ones.  In any base, an infinite repeating decimal of $b-1$s represents $1$.  We can see that by summing the geometric series.  $$0.(b-1)(b-1)(b-1)\ldots _b=(b-1)\cdot 0.11111\ldots_b\\=(b-1)(\frac 1b+\frac 1{b^2}+\frac 1{b^3}+\ldots )\\=(b-1) \frac 1{b-1} = 1$$

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: Both $.JJJJ\ldots _{20}$ and $0.9999\ldots _{10}$ equal $1$. Neither is closer. The point about finite decimals does not matter.

Comment: See my note below.

Comment: Ross, would you mind explaining why? It seems that .JJJ... gets closer to 1 faster then .999... and so .JJJ... is always between .999... and 1 no matter how far out you go.

Comment: You are confusing what is happening at finite stages from what happens at the limit.  Yes, after any given number of digits $0.JJJJ$ is greater than $0.9999$.  The distance from $1$ is $\frac `1{20^n}$ compared to $\frac 1{10^n}$.  The limit of both of those distances as $n \to \infty$ is zero.  What do you think $0.JJJJ\ldots_{20}- 0.99999\ldots_{10}$ is if not zero?  If it is zero, they are equal.

Comment: Ok, thanks I think I'm starting to get it, there is one think that needs to be cleared up. Is .999... in base 10 equal to .III... in base 20? Because, if they are then it would seem that the answer to .JJJ... in base 20 - .III in base 20 equals .111... in base 20.

Comment: No.  $I$ is the symbol for a digit $18$ in base $20$.  If you repeat $I$s, you get $\frac {18}{19}$.  The place values are different between base $10$ and base $20$ so you can't just double the digits.  Think about whole numbers.  It is not true that $9$ in base $10$ equals $I$ in base $20$, nor that $90$ in base $10$ equals $I0$ in base $20$.

Comment: So is .999... in base 20 the same as in base 10? Because that also seems to make things awkward. Why does .999... equal one in base 10 but not in base 20?

Comment: No, $0.99999\ldots_{20}$ would conventionally be written $\frac 9{19}$.  Just sum the geometric series it represents.  It is $\frac 9{20}+\frac 9{20^2}+\frac 9{20^3}+\ldots$

Comment: Thanks for your help.While I'm probably a bit more confused, I think I understand why my friend's argument was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. .9999999999... = 1

Simple proof: What is 1 - .9? 1 - .99? 1 - ,999?
What is 1 - .9999999999? 
So what is the **limit** as you get an infinite number of decimal 9's, of 1 - .99999999999 . . . ?

More formal proof: There is a rule that if you add the sum to infinity of $ar^n$ you get $\frac{a}{1-r}$ (proof in almost any calculus 2 text)
.9999999... = 9/10 + 9/100 + 9/1000 + ...
So the first term a = 9/10 or .9 and the multiplier r = 1/10 or .1
.9999999... = 9/10 + 9/100 + 9/1000 + ... = Sum from n = 0 to infinity of $(9/10)\cdot(1/10)^n = $ Sum from n = 0 to infinity of $.9\cdot.1^n$
Sum = $\frac{.9}{1 - .1} = \frac{.9}{.9} = 1$

In base 10 we have ten symbols, 0, 1, 2, . . ., 9
In base 2 there are two symbols, 0 and 1
In base 3 there are three sumbols, 0, 1, and 2

There is a pattern here.

Base 16, often used in computer science, uses sixteen symbols, 0. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, A, B, C, D, E, F.
A = ten, B = eleven, up to F = fifteen.  In base 16,  10 is NOT ten, but it is 1 * 16 + 0 * 1  (The 1 stands for 1 times the base).

Base 20 requires twenty symbols up to J (J base 20 = 19 base 10).

,191919.. is NOT written in base 20 but in bade 10, so you can't calculate base 20 with it. That is why your calculations came out all weird.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: Alonzo, I went into some detail to explain your misconceptions. 
The answer is (a) Yes .09999 . . .  = 1 and I showed you two proofs why; and (b) no, your question is dead wrong from the get-go and does not make sense because you are not even writing in base 20. 
If you don't happen to like an answer that does not make it a bad answer. It means you should take some time and read it over and try to learn and understand.

Comment: While you addressed that .999 = 1 that was not the core of my question, or even the part I was interested in. You object to me asking the question in a slightly awkward way, but that's not answering the question either.

Comment: One more time: .19191919... is NOT in base 20. Before you ask a question about base 20, you need to know what base 20 is and isn't. Your question as posted was meaningless. Several people have tried in various ways to show you what base 20 is so that you can understand how it works. You are not slightly awkward, you are WRONG.